# How to select ng-tab with ngFor in ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I get parameter from route so I can activate the corresponding tab.

I use ngFor to generate ng-tab, because the data is come from database. Here is the app.component.pug:

```
ngb-tabset(#t="ngbTabset")
    ngb-tab(*ngFor="let item of data" id="{{item.value}}")
        template(ngbTabTitle)
            a([routerLink]='["../", item.value]' routerLinkActive='active' innerHTML="{{item.name}}") 
        template(ngbTabContent) {{item.value}}
```

and here is the app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
    @ViewChild('t') ngbTabSet;    
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('view init..');
        this.route.params
            .subscribe((params: Params) => {
                console.log(params);
                //it's length was 0 at first
                this.ngbTabSet.select(params['system']);
            })
    }
}
```

But the ngbTabSet's lengh is 0 at first.

I try to not use ng-tab with ngFor, it works fine.

Is the problem is the view not generate completely when use ngFor?

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to bind activeId property on ngb tabset instead of using select method. Select method gives trouble for some reason but activeId binding works.